# PHP 301 Redirect _blank

Tags: php, redirect

I am moving legal content into my Zendesk support portal. I want to use a PHP 301 redirect as defined below because I have links in my native iOS and Android apps that link to these old pages.

Is there a way to "target='_blank'"?

SOURCE:

```
<?php
// PHP permanent URL redirect - generated by www.rapidtables.com
header("Location: https://talloo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205888306-Privacy-Policy", true, 301);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: No. The target is just a browser feature. There is no way to influence that in the response.

Comment: The sense of a serverside redirect is to tell the browser, that the requested page is at a different location. From this perspective, the browser __must__  load the page in to the current window, as the redirect URL is merely only an "alias". Redirecting in to a new window isn't the intention of a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any way to do that. header() just redirect current window in current window tab.

Comment: @DiegoGoesBauleo yes, you right, i edited my answer, thanks.

Comment: I just removed it because I thought I had sent it in the wrong thread. Anyways :)